# PHP memcached or Nginx memcached

Tags: nginx, memcached

What is better to use the memcached php or nginx? or can I use the two together? Help in performance using the two together? Why so I saw the nginx and php memcached has, so I was confused by which of the two to use.

Answer (score 1):

`memcached` is a key-value storage server, and `nginx` is a proxy server, neither can do the other's task, you can use them both together.

If you explain what you are trying to accomplish exactly I could provide a more useful answer.